# Skia: any benefit of using the CPU renderer over the GPU renderer

Tags: skiasharp, skia

I've created a small sample animation with SkiaSharp and it runs with 60FPS.
On a real Pixel 4 it has the following perfomance:

SKGLView (GPU Renderer):

- average Frametimes 0.5ms

SKCanvasView (CPU Renderer):

- average frametimes: 5ms

If the gpu renderer is so much faster:

**What's the usecase/benefit for using the cpu renderer?**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but I suppose that back then when Skia was created, not all devices might have had a graphics chip. Think of something like embedded devices running linux but on hardware lacking a GPU.

Comment: I thought of something similar. I guess initially there was only an OpenGL renderer. And from there going to a new platform takes some time to implement a complete GPU renderer (for webgl, metal, vulkan, tizen, etc). An meanwhile you can use the software renderer. But this is only guessing.